# Как записать кириллицу в Unicode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
with open("data/data.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:  
   f.write(json.dumps(result, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, indent=4))
```

Пытаюсь так записать, пробовал с encode() и подобные способы, но ничего не вышло.
Суть проблемы в том, что строка не считывается с файла, а приходит с интернета

Пробовал еще так:

```py
with open("data/data.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:  
    f.write(json.dumps(result, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, indent=4).encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

Результат:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\clash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 507, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\clash\Main\Programming\Discord_Selfbot\main.py", line 63, in on_message
    f.write(json.dumps(result, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, indent=4).encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 187-188: surrogates not allowed
```

Comment: Как именно она «приходит с интеренета» и с какого перепуга в ней оказались суррогатные пары?

Comment: пользуюсь discord.py-self и получаю информацию о всех каналах и их категории

Comment: Покажите ошибку полностью в вопросе, пока не очень понятно - кто у вас ругается: файл при записи строки или `encode/decode`.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил